# Simple c++ multithreading example not compiling in CentOS Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am a .NET Microsoft man trying to defect to Linux. I need to learn how to build multithreaded code in c++. But I dot stuck in the first pothole... I found this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *print_message_function( void *ptr );

main()
{
     pthread_t thread1, thread2;
     const char *message1 = "Thread 1";
     const char *message2 = "Thread 2";
     int  iret1, iret2;

     iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);
     iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message2);

     pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
     pthread_join( thread2, NULL);

     printf("Thread 1 returns: %d\n",iret1);
     printf("Thread 2 returns: %d\n",iret2);
     exit(0);
}

void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
     char *message;
     message = (char *) ptr;
     printf("%s \n", message);
}
```

But I cannot run this in Eclipse. I am getting errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [TestMySQL] Error 1   TestMySQL           C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `pthread_create' TestMySQL.cpp   /TestMySQL/src  line 16 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `pthread_create' TestMySQL.cpp   /TestMySQL/src  line 17 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `pthread_join'   TestMySQL.cpp   /TestMySQL/src  line 23 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `pthread_join'   TestMySQL.cpp   /TestMySQL/src  line 24 C/C++ Problem
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the `-ptread` compiler option. Same option for the linking command, of course.

Comment: The problem is in the linking, not compiling.

Comment: You need to link against libpthread.so library which is like: `g++ a.cpp -pthread`

Comment: +1 for the opening line!...

Comment: You may consider learning [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) which knows about [multi-threading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/multithreading/); then be sure to compile with [GCC 4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/) not some earlier version of  `g++`; and please learn how to compile on the command line (`g++ -Wall -std=c++11`, and [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) ...) because *Eclipse not a compiler* ...

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project -> Properties 
Navigate to C/C++ Build -> Settings
Select GCC C++ Linker 
Add "-pthread" to All Options box.

Solveded!

Thanks to all the commenter for pointing me in the right direction.